# Find all functions that satisfy the condition $f(xy,\frac{x}{y})=x^{2}-y^{2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functional-equations

Find all functions $f: (0, \infty)^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x,y >0$ the following equation holds
$$f(xy,\frac{x}{y})=x^{2}-y^{2}.$$

Can someone give any tips where to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

Make the change of variables:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
u = xy\\\\
v = \dfrac{x}{y}
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
u = y^{2}v\\\\
x = yv
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
y = \sqrt{\dfrac{u}{v}}\\\\
x = \sqrt{uv}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: +1: note that this suggests a single solution to the functional equation

Comment: Wow, this helped alot, thanks. 
But how should I show that no other solutions exist?